# DotRAS.dll not working on Windows 10 Update 1803

Tags: vb.net, dotras

I have a small VB.NET program, which creates a VPN connection.
This is working until (and including) Windows 10 Update 1709.
But since the Update 1803 I always get an exception:

*DotRas.RasException: An incorrect structure size was detected.
   at DotRas.Internal.ThrowHelper.ThrowRasException(Int32 errorCode)
   at DotRas.Internal.RasHelper.GetEntryProperties(RasPhoneBook phoneBook, String entryName)
   at DotRas.RasEntryCollection.Load()
   at DotRas.RasPhoneBook.Open(String phoneBookPath)*

Following my working Code Sub (until 1709)

```
Private Sub CreateVPN(VpnName As String, Destination As String, bAllUsers As Boolean)
    Dim PresharedKey As String = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

    Try
        Dim PhoneBook As New RasPhoneBook
        Dim sUsedPhoneBook As String = sPhoneBook
        If bAllUsers Then sUsedPhoneBook = sAllUserPhoneBook

        PhoneBook.Open(sUsedPhoneBook)

        'First remove existing VPN with same name, if exist!
        Try
            PhoneBook.Entries.Remove(VpnName)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Dim VpnEntry As RasEntry = RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(VpnName, Destination, DotRas.RasVpnStrategy.L2tpOnly, DotRas.RasDevice.Create(VpnName, DotRas.RasDeviceType.Vpn))
        VpnEntry.Options.UsePreSharedKey = True
        VpnEntry.Options.IPHeaderCompression = True
        VpnEntry.Options.SoftwareCompression = True
        VpnEntry.Options.NetworkLogOn = True
        VpnEntry.NetworkProtocols.IPv6 = False
        VpnEntry.Options.RequireEap = False
        VpnEntry.Options.RequirePap = True
        VpnEntry.Options.RequireChap = True
        VpnEntry.Options.RequireMSChap2 = True
        VpnEntry.Options.RequireEncryptedPassword = False
        VpnEntry.Options.UseLogOnCredentials = False
        VpnEntry.Options.CacheCredentials = False
        VpnEntry.DnsSuffix = "YYYYYYY.local"
        VpnEntry.Options.UseDnsSuffixForRegistration = True

       ' *********** THE FOLLOWING LINE WILL CRASH ON WINDOWS 10 1803 **********
        PhoneBook.Entries.Add(VpnEntry)
        VpnEntry.UpdateCredentials(RasPreSharedKey.Client, PresharedKey)
        If txt_Username.Text <> "" AndAlso txt_Password.Text <> "" Then
            VpnEntry.UpdateCredentials(New Net.NetworkCredential(txt_Username.Text, txt_Password.Text), False)
            VpnEntry.Options.CacheCredentials = True
            VpnEntry.Update()
        End If

        PhoneBook.Dispose()

        txt_Status.Text = VpnName & " successful added."
        txt_Status.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error while adding " & VpnName & "." & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me? 
I didn't found an updated DotRAS.dll. 
Best would be a working example without external DLL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiple question about it, this is a bug in the Redstone 4 preview edition.  Microsoft promised a fix in an update scheduled for May 8th.

Comment: Hi Hans
Thank you very much for your comment. Let's hope, this will really be fixed.

Comment: I did not change anything in my code. But now it's working again. Seems that some updates from Microsoft has fixed it!